# which Sources of asset field are checked

Tags: craft3, assets-field

I have an asset field (craft\fields\Asset), how do I figure out which Sources it can use? (Which of the Sources boxes are checked)?

This is for Craft 3, and I'd like to do it in twig (I have the asset field in twig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all available sources with

```
field.getSourceOptions()
```

Which returns you an array of all sources, no matter if they are selected or not (just to get the ids and such)

and with

```
field.sources
```

you'll receive an array if you selected several sources or a string (`*`) if all are selected.